# Python requests - save cookies in file and reuse it

Tags: python, python-requests, pickle

So I encounter a problem to use my `cookie` file.

I have a simple script that login to system and make several `requests`.

So after the login I make several `requests` and before the log out I save this file:

```
def __save_user_cookies_file__(self) -> None:
     file_name = f'{self.user}_cookies'
     with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
         pickle.dump(self.api.session.cookies, f)
```

And Next time instead of `login` I just load this `cookies` file and use it:

```
def __load_user_cookies_file__(self) -> None:
    with open(f'{self.user}_cookies', 'rb') as f:
        self.api.session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))
```

And use this object:

```
self.api.session
```

So at the first time this work fine and I can do my stuff using this `cookies` file instead of `login` first and the problem starts when I try to use this file again at the next day.
So I try to save this file again and obtained the same results, It looks like my user not logged in.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies expire, and the authentication cookies you receive from the URL you request have an `expires` field. In your case, those may only be valid for a day.

You can check those expiry dates with:

```
import datetime as datetime
for cookie in list(self.api.session.cookies):
    print(f"Cookie {cookie.name} \
            expires on {datetime.fromtimestamp(cookie.expires)}")
```